# Trouble - success class not disappearing when entering valid and then error data in jQuery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-validate

I have such trouble when I'm entering valid data it is ok

[image]

but after that, when I'm entering WRONG DATA appears this situation:

[image]

Here is my js code, which is related to error/valid classes:

```
   errorElement: "div",
    wrapper: "div",  // a wrapper around the error message
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    element.before(error);
    offset = element.offset();
    error.css('right', offset.right);
    },
    success: "valid"
```

and CSS code:

```
    label.error{
color:#b76b6f;
width: 200px;
height: 60px;
text-align: right;
position: absolute;
margin-left: 280px;
margin-top: -20px;
margin-bottom: 0;
background: url('../images/not_valid.png') no-repeat;
background-position:100% 80%;
 }

 div.error{
 color:#b76b6f;
 width: 200px;
 height: 60px;
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 180px;
 margin-top: -25px;
  display: block;
  background-color:#F3E6E6;
  background: url('../images/not_valid.png') no-repeat;
 background-position:100% 100%;
 text-align: right;
  }
```

Generated HTML in this situation:

```
 <div class="field2"><label for="user_password">Password</label>
  <div class="valid"></div>
   <div><div for="passworrd" generated="true" class="error" style="display: block;">Please enter at least 6 characters.</div></div>
  <input type="password" size="30" name="user[password]" id="passworrd" class="passwords error"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what the `focusCleanup` option is for.

EDIT:

Try using `validClass: "valid"` instead of `success: "valid"`.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood the problem. You're not complaining about the error message, you're complaining that the green check-mark is still there. I'll check some more.

Comment: Now, it doesn't add valid class at all.

Comment: I don't understand why. The documentation says "This class is added to an element after it was validated and considered valid." Do you have your own "unhighlight" function? It looks like adding and removing validClass and errorClass is done by the default highlight and unhighlight functions.

Comment: Barmar, sorry, that spent your time. I found my error. It is so stupid, shame on me.